# rsync fails to exclude '#filename#' file names

Tags: rsync

I have this rsync command:

'rsync -va --delete --exclude-from=rsync_exclusions.txt SourceA DestinationB'

rsync_exclusions.txt contains a single line:

`#script.sh#`

The command runs fine, except the #script.sh# file gets added to the destination.

I tried escaping the file name in the exclusion file so:

`/#script.sh/#`

which also did not work. Any idea how to exclude this file, without resorting to renaming it without the sharps? Note that other file names in the the same dir get excluded fine with the same command when added to the exclusion file.

Comment: Does the actual filename have hashes (#)?

Comment: Yes, the filenames have hashes at the beg. and end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `[#]script.sh[#]` in the excludes file.

Comment: Still does not get excluded. Incidentally, when I list the dir with #script.sh# file in bash, it shows the file as '#script.sh#', note the single quotes. But this file in OSX Finder shows up without single quotes. Also, tried renaming it with mv '#script.sh#' #script.sh# - fails with "files are same" message.

Comment: Why do you need to have hashes in the filename? Perhaps this could help me provide a better answer.

Comment: Obviously, I can rename the file. The question is/was how to exclude filenames with hashes from being rsynced, if at all possible.

Comment: Exactly how is your file named? Is it `'#script.sh#'` or `#script.sh#`?

Comment: It is named #script.sh#

Comment: The  above solution works for me if the file is named #script.sh#

Comment: I use rsync  version 2.6.9  protocol version 29, on OS X 10.9.5; assuming you referred to `[#]` solution, this did not work here. Which version and on what OS do you use?

Comment: rsync 3.1.2 protocol version 31 on Windows 10, rsync 3.1.1 protocol version 31 on Raspberry Pi, rsync 3.1.1 protocol version 31 on OpenWRT. It works on all three.